# Replacing a substring between start and end point in a string

Tags: .net, regex, vb.net, string, replace

**This post is related to Visual Basic 2010**

Okay so, I have this string:

```
"{hello, world, hello, world, hello, world}"
```

Now say that I want to replace the first occurance of the word "hello", by defining the index of the first character, and the index of the last character. So that it doesn't for example replace the second or third occurance of the word "hello".

I just want the first occurance of the word hello replaced with another that may or may not vary in length.

How could I be doing this? Regex?

Comment: Do you need the comma taken out as well?

Comment: No, I just want the first occurance of the word hello replaced with another that may or may not vary in length.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do what you want. If you know what word to remove, you can just use its length to determine what characters should be removed.

```
Dim wordToRemove As String = "hello"
Dim wordIndex As Integer = yourString.IndexOf(wordToRemove)

If wordIndex >= 0 Then
    yourString = yourString.Remove(wordIndex, wordToRemove.Length)
    yourString = yourString.Insert(wordIndex, "newword")
End If
```

Comment: This did the trick. Put it in a neat little function for easier use. http://pastebin.com/1xcWRrbA

Comment: @JeffReed you are welcome! :) Please do not forget to mark as answered.